# I need an element to be a child of other without inheriting certains properties

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

[image]

```
<span id="priority-dot-open-menu">
                    <span id="priority-menu">
                        <span class="tooltip-top"></span>
                        <span id="priority-dot-blue"></span>
                        <span id="priority-dot-yellow"></span>
                        <span id="priority-dot-red"></span>
                    </span>
                </span>
```

```
/* The popup menu - hidden by default */
#priority-menu {      
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 150%;
    left: -50%;    
    border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
    z-index: 9;    
    max-width: 300px;    
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;          
}

#priority-dot-open-menu { 
    position: relative;   
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 50%;    
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0.8;
    cursor: pointer;    
}

#priority-dot-open-menu:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

My #priority-menu (column with the 3 dots) is a child of the dot above (#priority-dot-open-menu). I need it to be so I can use absolute positioning. However it's also inheriting certain properties/values, like opacity and hovering which I don't want to. What would be the ideal solution? 
https://jsfiddle.net/moq2bwLj/ (the menu doesn't open on js fiddle, it's just for code-viewing purposes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Child elements in CSS *automatically* inherit the rules applied to their parents; there is nothing you can do to prevent this. What you **can** do, however, is to *override* this behaviour by crafting a rule that targets the child, changing it to the **[`initial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial)** value:

```
#priority-menu {
  cursor: initial;
  opacity: initial;
}
```

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. However... it only works for "cursor". The opacity behaves exactly the same way.